# How to tell in advance if CountVectorizer will throw ValueError: empty vocabulary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, nlp

Is it possible to know in advance if `CountVectorizer` will throw

> ValueError: empty vocabulary?

Basically, I have a corpus of documents and I'd like to filter out those that won't pass the `CountVectorizer` (I'm using `stop_words='english'`)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could identify those documents using `build_analyzer()`. Try this!

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
corpus = [
    'This is the first document.',
    'This document is the second document.',
    'And this is the third one.',
    'Is this the first document?',
    'this is to',
    'she has'
]
analyzer = CountVectorizer(stop_words='english').build_analyzer()
filter_condtn = [True if analyzer(doc) else False for doc in corpus ]

#[True, True, False, True, False, False]
```

P.S. : Am too confused to see all the words in third document is in stop words.